# ¿Cómo se exporta una colección y variables de entorno en Postman?

Tags: postman

¿Alguna persona caritativa me recuerda cómo se exportaba una colección y variables de entorno en **Postman**?

Comment: Esta pregunta no trata sobre programación dentro del ámbito definido en el [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colección: en el menú lateral izquierdo, en la parte que pone Collections, haces un clic sobre los 3 puntos, se te despliegan una serie de opciones y le das a Export

Variables de entorno: a la derecha del todo, justo al lado del botón del ojo le das a la rueda, seleccionar la colección y le das a download.

Answer (score 0):

Click derecho en tu colección de postman, que tienes a la izquierda.

Le das a Export, y luego eliges la carpeta destino de la exportación.